# how to send a mail using jquery or javascript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

how to send a mail using jquery or javascript in HTML page.I used

```
<form action="mailto:you@yourdmainhere.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >  
FirstName:<input type="text" name="FirstName">  
Email:<input type="text" name="Email">  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

But it opens email appication in my system.I have to send it manually too

Comment: You need to do this on the server side. Try NodeJS if you want to use JavaScript, otherwise plain old PHP will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send e-mail via JavaScript. You'll need something server-side.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use AJAX for this....using ajax pass email & name to remote page and process the email on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not know how to talk `SMTP` so you can't at client side.